# Why do some brand new documents show up in user recycle bins as well?

Tags: 2010, file-upload, recycle-bin

SharePoint 2010 / SQL Server 2008 R2

Sometimes (but not always) when a user uploads or directly saves a new file into a document library in my environment that document saves to the desired location but also shows up in the user's recycle bin as a <1KB item.

Why is this?

Comment: When you say "directly saves" what method are you referring to? Is it possible this is an existent item that is being overwritten and the old file is going to the bin?

Comment: By "directly saves" I mean they have a brand new document, click Save As, and save that document into the SharePoint server via a mapped drive pointed at a document library. The file has never been saved to any local or remote location before this point.

Comment: I suspect if this will help as this only happens "sometimes" but can you check if you doc lib has any event receivers attached to it using http://speventreceiverman.codeplex.com/ and also does it happens for a specific doc lib and whether it happens for specific types of documents ? :)

Comment: @TimeToShine - Can you give me a few details on how to do that?

Comment: @JonnyP It was difficult to explain it in comments so I put it as an answer, if you couldn't find ny event receiver attached then we will try to find another solution.

Comment: @newuser: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

It might help you with your question,

Select Site/Web where your document library is located using these two drop down menu lists which are auto populated when you open [speventreceivermanager's](http://speventreceiverman.codeplex.com/) exe file as shown in picture below,

[image]

Now select your document library from list of libraries on left side,

[image]

When you will click on your doc lib, you will see all of the available event receivers for that particular library and if any of event receiver has child nodes then it means library has a event receiver attached to it and then you can either remove that event receiver or look into it (you can note down name of it and then you know which receiver it is) to find out whats happening in the code (you will have to check event receiver's solution which will be somewhere saved by developer of ER)

[image]

You might be looking at item added or item adding event receivers specially.

Comment: Finally checked and there are no event receivers on the document library in question.